# Can I use Android CRT power-off animation built into Android 4.1 JellyBean?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an app and I'd like to use the Android CRT power-off animation built into Android 4.1 for my onPause activity transition animation. However, I have not been able to find out where this animation xml resides inside the Android source code. My guess would be that it's somewhere inside some sources as the animation seems fairly complex. It's not just a simple scale/translate thing.

This is how it looks like : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zFwpb_LDHQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. It's not a part of the SDK. You would probably have to create your own. I am guessing, it's not an XML, rather it would be some native code or at-least OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this animation `mElectronBeamOnAnimator` out, it's can be found in:

> /frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/power/DisplayPowerController.java

And do not forget to set `mElectronBeamFadesConfig` to false, which will use mode `ElectronBeam.MODE_WARM_UP`, which is CRT effect.

As Bibek said, it uses `openGL` to draw this animation rather than just an xml file.
Hope this will help.